# Setting maximum time for code to run in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have one line of code that opens a word document but occasionally, this code fails and locks the entire program indefinitely.

```
Set oDoc = oApp.Documents.Open(sF)
```

Ideally I would want to be able to abort this line of code after a certain time has passed. I looked into some multithreading examples using VB6 without much success.

Comment: As it's a blocking call, you don't have this much control in VB6. Essentially, it's blocked waiting for something to happen in Word and until it returns, there is nothing your VB6 application can do.

Comment: Word is probably showing a dialog but you can't see it - try changing the visibility/modality of it/your app